# Cannot find stuff for my Kernel and Kernel Headers

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I don't know what to say but I want to install Virtualbox and stuff but there is a problem with my kernel.
 Ubuntu says my kernel is 4.4.0-042stabl42.1 but no program can find something for that. When i do `modprobe vboxdrv` it says: `Paket linux-headers-4.4.0-042stab142.1 kann nicht gefunden werden`. In English it means paket linux-headers-4.4.0-042stab142.1 could not be found.

please help, sorry for my bad English and

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`  is not working.

Comment: Where and how exactly did you find and install kernel version 4.4.0-042stabl42.1? Wherever it was found hopefully also has a deb package for linux-headers-4.4.0-042stabl42.1-generic. Find it, install it and try again. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i did uname -r and it said 4.4.0-042stab142.1
it was installed by default

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have installed?

Comment: Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Comment: That is interesting because I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 cleanly and it comes with kernel version 4.15.0-45-generic.  The naming convention that I have stated here is how Canonical does all their kernel versions.  I have never seen Canonical include a kernel version like you have listed there.

Comment: it could be that the kernel comes with from the server hoster i rented the server and this was installed when i do the updates it also downloads the ubuntu updates over the servers from the serverhoster and not the official ones

Comment: is there any way to update to a offical kernel version ?

Comment: Install the `linux-image-generic` metapackage. It will drag in the newest Ubuntu kernel for your release (4.4.0-179). However, it's likely that you had some reason to install a non-Ubuntu kernel; returning to an Ubuntu kernel might break whatever you were trying to accomplish.